# Detect deepest list link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I search for jQuery code which detect click on deepest link in ul, other links may not refer (event.preventDefault()). I use this with Wordpress function:

```
wp_list_categories(
    array( 
        'title_li' => '',
        'depth' => 0,
        'child_of' => $this_cat->cat_ID
    )
);
```

List code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-25"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/category/abc">ABC Category</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-26"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/category/abc/xyz">XYZ Category</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach, which checks for `ul` children in the `li` having the clicked link:

```
$('li > a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if( !$(this).parent().children('ul').length ) {
        console.log( 'This is the deepest link' );
    }
});
```

```js
$('li > a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if( !$(this).parent().children('ul').length ) {
        console.log( 'This is the deepest link' );
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-25"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/category/abc">ABC Category</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-26"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/category/abc/xyz">XYZ Category</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```